# Make Button Visible Based on ComboBox selection

Tags: wpf, xaml

How do I make a Button show if a certain value is selected in a ComboBox using XAML ?

This is what I have tried.

Thanks

```
        <ComboBox x:Name="ComboBox" Margin="171,102,426,271">
        <ComboBoxItem>Testing</ComboBoxItem>
        <ComboBoxItem>Again</ComboBoxItem>
        <ComboBoxItem>Finally</ComboBoxItem>
    </ComboBox>

    <Button Margin="10, 0, 0, 0" >
        <Button.Style>
            <Style TargetType="Button">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SelectedIndex, ElementName=ComboBox}" Value="Testing">
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Button.Style>
    </Button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The binding path should be `SelectedItem.Content` for your trigger to work:

```
<Button Margin="10, 0, 0, 0" >
    <Button.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Button">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SelectedItem.Content, ElementName=ComboBox}" Value="Testing">
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Button.Style>
</Button>
```

You are currently binding to the `SelectedIndex` property and this one never has a value of "Testing". The currently selected `ComboBoxItem`'s `Content` property may have though.

If you want to show the `Button` when the "Testing" option is selected, you should also modify the value fo your setter:

```
<Button Margin="10, 0, 0, 0" >
    <Button.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SelectedItem.Content, ElementName=ComboBox}" Value="Testing">
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Button.Style>
</Button>
```

Comment: Thats great, seems to work. It seems to be doing the opposite, hiding on the  wrong optionw. I've tried making the button hidden initially, then set the value as Visible but it doesn't show.

This does but opposite

                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SelectedItem.Content, ElementName=ComboBox}" Value="Testing">
                            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>

Comment: This should do it but it remains hidden


 <Button Margin="171,277,33,108" Visibility="Hidden">
            <Button.Style>
                <Style TargetType="Button">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SelectedItem.Content, ElementName=ComboBox}" Value="Testing">
                            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </Button.Style>
        </Button>

Comment: @IamAJoker: You can't set the Visibility property of the Button like that. You should set the default value in the style. Again, please see the second code snippet in my answer.

Comment: @mn8 Yeah, I was busy trying to paste the code initially, whilst you were replying so didn't see it was edited. I didn't know about the setting answer as correct, then creating a different question. Sorry

Answer (score 2):

A better approach is to bind the controls to a view model and to integrate the logic there. See: [Explain Combo Box Binding In MVVM - WPF](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/explain-combo-box-binding-in-mvvm-wpf/).

As an example we create a window for editing of person data. It contains a combobox where the user can select a city. When a certain city is selected, a button is is displayed, otherwise it is hidden.

You could have a view model looking like this

```
public class PersonViewModel: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _city;
    public string City
    {
        get { return _city; }
        set {
            if (value != _city) {
                _city = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(City));
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(MyButtonVisibility));
            }
        }
    }

    public List<string> Cities { get; } = new List<string> { "Austin", "Boston", "Chicago"};

    public Visibility MyButtonVisibility => City == "Boston"
        ? Visibility.Visible
        : Visibility.Hidden;

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    // Other properties

    private string _firstName;
    public string FirstName
    {
        get { return _firstName; }
        set {
            if (value != _firstName) {
                _firstName = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(FirstName));
            }
        }
    }

    private string _lastName;
    public string LastName
    {
        get { return _lastName; }
        set {
            if (value != _lastName) {
                _lastName = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(LastName));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note that it implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`. It has a `Cities` collection used to display the combobox items and a `City` property for the selected city.

We also need a property for the button visibility (`MyButtonVisibility`). Note that when the selected city changes, we also raise the `PropertyChanged` event for `MyButtonVisibility` to tell WPF to requery the button visibility.

In the window's constructor we assign the view model:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DataContext = new PersonViewModel();
}
```

The XAML code for the combobox is

```
<ComboBox x:Name="citiesComboBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="116,96,0,0"
    VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"
    ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Cities}"    
    SelectedItem="{Binding Path=City}"  
/>
```

The XAML code for the button is

```
<Button Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="116,164,0,0"
    VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"
    Visibility="{Binding MyButtonVisibility}"
/>
```

By the magic of WPF binding, now the button appears or disappears automatically, when you select cities.

Comment: Interesting! I didn't get why we need to use First Name and Last Name in the code behind? Is that extra?

Comment: That's not code behind. It is not in the window code, it's a separate class called a View Model, i.e. the data source of the form. First and last name are there to be bound to textboxes. The only code behind required is `DataContext = new PersonViewModel();` or an equivalent code getting person data from somewhere. Everything else is done by binding, not code. Even loading the combobox items is not required anymore in code. Google for [MVVM](https://www.google.com/search?q=MVVM).